# Solving a coupled differential equations system using time splitting

Tags: c, differential-equations, finite-difference

```
/******************************************************************************

                            Online C Compiler.
                Code, Compile, Run and Debug C program online.
Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to compile and execute it.

*******************************************************************************/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PI  3.141592

void read_input(double *D, double *L, int *nx, double *t_F);

double main(void) {
  /******************************/
  /* Declarations of parameters */
  /******************************/
  /* Number of grid points */                  
  int nx;
  /* Length of domain */
  double L;
  /* Equation coefficients */
  double D;
  /* Length of time to run simulation. */
  double t_F;

  /* Read in from file; */
  read_input(&D, &L, &nx, &t_F);

  /* Grid spacing */
  double dx = L/nx;
  double invdx2 = 1.0/(dx*dx);      
  /* Time step */
  double dt = 0.25/invdx2; // changed to 0.25/dx^2 to satisfy the stability condition

  /************************************************/
  /* Solution Storage at Current / Next time step */
  /************************************************/
  double *uc, *un, *vc, *vn;
  /* Time splitting solutions */
  double *uts1, *uts2, *vts1, *vts2;
  /* Derivative used in finite difference */
  double deriv;

  /* Allocate memory according to size of nx */
  uc = malloc(nx  * sizeof(double));
  un = malloc(nx * sizeof(double));
  vc = malloc(nx * sizeof(double));
  vn = malloc(nx * sizeof(double));
  uts1 = malloc(nx * sizeof(double));
  uts2 = malloc(nx * sizeof(double));
  vts1 = malloc(nx * sizeof(double));
  vts2 = malloc(nx * sizeof(double));

  /* Check the allocation pointers */
  if (uc==NULL||un==NULL||vc==NULL||vn==NULL||uts1==NULL||
  uts2==NULL||vts1==NULL||vts2==NULL) {
    printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
    return 1;
  }
  
  int k;
  double x;
  /* Current time */
  double ctime;

  /* Initialise arrays */
  for(k = 0; k < nx; k++) {
    x = k*dx;
    uc[k]  = 1.0 + sin(2.0*PI*x/L);
    vc[k]  = 0.0;
    /* Set other arrays to 0 */
    uts1[k] = 0; uts2[k] = 0;
    vts1[k] = 0; vts2[k] = 0;
  }

  /* Loop over timesteps */ 
  while (ctime < t_F){
  
    /* Rotation factors for time-splitting scheme. */
    double cfac = cos(dt); //changed from 2*dt to dt
    double sfac = sin(dt);

    /* First substep for diffusion equation, A_1 */ 
    for (k = 0; k < nx; k++) {
      x = k*dx;
      /* Diffusion at half time step. */
      deriv = (uc[k-1] + uc[k+1] - 2*uc[k])*invdx2 ;
      uts1[k] = uc[k] + (D * deriv + vc[k])* 0.5*dt; //
      deriv = (vc[k-1] + vc[k+1] - 2*vc[k])*invdx2;
      vts1[k] = vc[k] + (D * deriv - uc[k]) * 0.5*dt;
    }

    /* Second substep for decay/growth terms, A_2 */
    for (k = 0; k < nx; k++) {
      x = k*dx;
      /* Apply rotation matrix to u and v, */
      uts2[k] = cfac*uts1[k] + sfac*vts1[k];
      vts2[k] = -sfac*uts1[k] + cfac*vts1[k];
    }

    /* Third substep for diffusion terms, A_1 */
    for (k = 0; k < nx; k++) {
      x = k*dx;
      deriv = (uts2[k-1] + uts2[k+1] - 2*uts2[k])*invdx2;
      un[k] = uts2[k] + (D * deriv + vts2[k]) * 0.5*dt;
      deriv = (vts2[k-1] + vts2[k+1] - 2*vts2[k])*invdx2;
      vn[k] = vts2[k] + (D * deriv - uts2[k]) * 0.5*dt;
    }
       
    /* Copy next values at timestep to u, v arrays. */
    memcpy(uc,un, sizeof(double) * nx);
    memcpy(vc,vn, sizeof(double) * nx);

    /* Increment time. */   
    ctime += dt;
    for (k = 0; k < nx; k++ ) {
      x = k*dx;
      printf("%g %g %g %g\n",ctime,x,uc[k],vc[k]);
    }
    
  }
  /* Free allocated memory */
  free(uc); free(un);
  free(vc); free(vn);
  free(uts1); free(uts2);
  free(vts1); free(vts2);

  return 0;
}

// The lines below don't contain any bugs! Don't modify them
void read_input(double *D, double *L, int *nx, double *t_F) {
   FILE *infile;
   if(!(infile=fopen("input.txt","r"))) {
       printf("Error opening file\n");
       exit(1);
   }
   if(4!=fscanf(infile,"%lf %lf %d %lf",D,L,nx,t_F)) {
       printf("Error reading parameters from file\n");
       exit(1);
   }
   fclose(infile);
}
```

So this is the code. It is meant to solve the following differential equations:

du/dt - Dd^2u/dx^2 - v = 0

dv/dt - Dd^2v/dx^2 + u = 0

It splits the equations into two parts. The second x derivative part(A1) and the decay part which contains u and v(A2) . It uses two half steps(0.5dt) for A1 and 1 full step of dt for A2. I know how to do time splitting but i dont know whether i have done it correctly here.

This is for an assignment and i have fixed all the errors and i am just trying to make the code work as intended. I have never had to solve something similar to this so i am definitely very stuck right now. The solution converges but i think its wrong. Any ideas why? Am not looking for someone to outright tell me what am doing wrong, just guide me in the right direction if you know what i mean.

PS: When i compile the code with gcc i get a warning about double main(void). Why might that be?

Comment: how should we debug "I think the solution is wrong"? If you think that, use equations to which you know the correct solutions and check whether you get them. If not, you have a lead.

Comment: "double main(void). Why might that be? "use `int main()`.

Comment: Use a debugger like gdb and go step by step on every instruction and solve the issue or simplify it atleast.

Comment: Ok i will give the debugger a go.

Comment: Please check the lexicon of your choice and use a pi constant with enough digits for double precision or 3 more. `sin(PI)` should be in the range of the machine constant for double. Or if you want to make a statement, be brave and define pi as 3 (or 22/7).

Comment: @LutzLehmann why do the signs need to be switched? Can you expand on that please? Also how can i impose boundary conditions, such that u[x] =u[x+L]

Comment: Sorry, sunday afternoon blindness, needs more coffee. If the time derivatives are isolated, the sign of the code result. /// One common strategy is to border the arrays with extra cells that get the values from one period away copied. One has to work this out, but one probably only needs this extension to one side, ensuring `x[0]=x[L], x[L+1]=x[1]`, computing the vector fields for indices `1..L` and copying the periodic values as said.

Comment: what i attempted to do is say:

Comment: uc[nx] = uc[0];
    uc[-1] = uc[nx-1];
    vc[nx+1] = vc[0];
    vc[-1] = vc[nx-1];

Comment: if this is correct should i add this inside the for loop after i used memcpy to copy the arrays? If not, then where does this need to go?